GCP edit loadbalancer frontend using gcloud command line option
I have a requirement to update ssl policy of GCP internal load balancer frontend using gcloud. I cannot see the option. Could someone please help me with this.
My original requirement is to attach ssl policy to a GKE ingress created internal load balancer. However GCP currently does not support that using Ingress and frontendconfig (this is for attaching the ssl policy). Hence thinking of attaching the ssl policy to the frontend once the load balancer is created.

Playing around gcloud command got the solution.
gcloud compute target-https-proxies update  --region=<your region/can be global> --ssl-policy=
target https proxy name - you will get this name from your load balancer
